# Gradual delete job not deleting the site content

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I used gradual delete option to delete the share point site with 150GB data.

The gradual delete job is configured to run daily.

The job initially ran for a day and deleted 80 GB data in one schedule.

Later it is not deleting any data on that content database hosting the deleted site.

I checked the timer job history and the job is ending in 1 minute.

How can i check this job running fine or not and troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: is the site size was 150 GB? if you run get-spdeletedsite, are you able to see the deleted site in the list?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP, site size is 150GB and i am not getting the site information when i run get-spdeletedsite.

Comment: when you check the size of database, are you seeing the total size of the db and are u seeing any free space in your DB? did you shrink DB?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP, yes i can see the total size of database and free space in database is showing 85GB . This 85GB free space is noticed after gradual delete job triggered first time and ran for 36 hours. Later this delete job is completing within a minute and not changing the free space. I did not yet shrink the database . Database total size is 330GB.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP, one more thing is, there is another site in the same content database which is getting updated on daily basis with documents from end users side. So is this existing site occupying the white space,  released from the gradual delete job? if so, how can i confirm that?

Comment: Check the size of existing site, from central admin you can see the quota of site and existing size....btw this what I am thinking

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP, i can check the  site of size in Central admin and it is growing in mega bytes every day.  I thought to track the table row count on docstreams table . Is it fine to run the sql query in this content database against the docstreams table with siteid given as deleted siteid with nolock .  If this docstreams table row count is decreasing for this deletedsite, i believe that gradual delete job is clearing the content.

Comment: no thats not fine, i think if the other sites are in that db are big then it may make sense